# UIImageView is ignoring my ContentMode setting

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I've found some other answers here, but they don't seem to apply/work, so I figure it might be due to my particular code.

In my app, I have an array of UIImages, which are actually scaled down photos taken by the iPhone camera.

I am attempting to show the UIImage within a scrollView, correctly scaled to show the entire image.

This is my code:

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;

CGFloat contentOffset = 0.0f;

pageControl.numberOfPages = [imageArray count];
pageControl.currentPage = 0;

for(UIImage *image in imageArray)
{
    NSLog(@"image width = %f, image height = %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);

    CGRect imageViewFrame = CGRectMake(contentOffset, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width,                 scrollView.frame.size.height);

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];  //I've tried others, but nothing seems to show the entire image
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
    contentOffset += scrollView.frame.size.width;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(contentOffset, 0)];
}
```

Just to note, this is a portrait-oriented app and the image itself was taken in portrait orientation.

The NSLog output:

```
image width = 387.200012, image height = 518.400024
```

The image that I see show up on the UIImageView (within the scrollview) is a zoomed up image of the center of the image, no matter what I change the contentmode to.

What am I doing wrong here?  thank you!

Comment: The content mode fails to work if you scale the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is what I had commented earlier: the scaling factor of the UIImage caused the ContentMode not to work. Or at least, made it seem not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You set a content size for the *scrollView* with a height of 0 and the *contentOffset* as width ... that obviously can't work.

You have to set the content size of the scroll view to the size your image has. That is the meaning of the content size - if it is bigger than the scroll view's size, the scroll view will let you scroll to see the parts that are not on the screen.

What you apparently want to do is to set the frame of the **imageView** to a *contentOffset* of n times the width of the screen so you can scroll horizontally through the images. So, set the size of the *UIImageView* to your screen size, and it's origin to (n * screenSize.width, 0), and the scroll view's content size to ((n+1)*screenSize.width, screenSize.height), with n being the image count.

Comment: Actually, the scrollview is working perfectly, it's just that the imageview is not respecting the contentmode.

I found the problem though.  The UIImage had a scale factor of 5, which I had set earlier in the program.  Fixing this corrected the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been asked and answered but it seems there is another cause for this issue lately.  As of **tvOS 9.1**, setting `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` seems to render `contentMode` obsolete (a possible bug) for `UIImageView`.  I hope this helps someone.